# Does the new Windows 7 phone platform use Silverlight for it's UI?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I created a new Windows 7 project it mentioned Silverlight. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can develop apps for WP7 in either Silverlight or XNA.

Silverlight on the WP7 platform is based on Silverlight 3 at this stage with some inclusions/exclusions specific to suit the mobile platform.

The Mix 2010 and Tech Ed 2010 NA sessions have some good introductory videos in the keynotes and breakouts that gives some good background knowledge.

There is also a post here which clarifies which is best to use for which type of apps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the Foundation for Windows Phone is Silverlight